# Select elements row-wise based on single array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array `d` of size `(N,T)`, out of which I need to select elements using `index` of shape `(N,)`, where the first element corresponds to the index in the first row, etc... how would I do that?

For example

```
>>> d
Out[748]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
>>> index
Out[752]: array([5, 6, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Expected Output:

```
array([[5],
       [6],
       [2])
```

Which is an array containing the fifth element of the first row, the 6th element of the second row and the second element of the third row.

**Update**

Since I will have sufficiently larger `N`, I was interested in the speed of the different methods for higher `N`. With `N = 30000`:

```
>>> %timeit np.diag(e.take(index2, axis=1)).reshape(N*3, 1)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.9 s per loop
>>> %timeit e.ravel()[np.arange(e.shape[0])*e.shape[1]+index2].reshape(N*3, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 287 µs per loop
```

Finally, you suggest `reshape()`. As I want to leave it as general as possible (without knowing `N`), I instead use `[:,np.newaxis]` - it seems to increase duration from `287µs` to `288µs`, which I'll take :)

Comment: Is the final output an array of three different arrays, like you've printed here? Or just one array with three elements?

Comment: Finally, I want to add the final output to the initial array. The way I printed it here, I can simply do `dNew = append(d, expectedOutput, axis=-1)`. Other final output that also allows this is equally welcome.

Comment: If speed is important you should check my second edit then if it also improves on your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be ugly but more efficient:

```
>>> d.ravel()[np.arange(d.shape[0])*d.shape[1]+index]
array([5, 6, 2])
```

**edit**

As pointed out by @deinonychusaur the statement above can be written as clean as:

```
d[np.arange(index.size),index]
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be nicer ways, but a combo of `take`, `diag` and `reshape` would do:

```
In [137]: np.diag(d.take(index, axis=1)).reshape(3, 1)
Out[137]: 
array([[5],
       [6],
       [2]])
```

**EDIT**

Comparisons with @Emanuele Paolinis' alterative, adding reshape to it to match the sought output:

```
In [142]: %timeit d.reshape(d.size)[np.arange(d.shape[0])*d.shape[1]+index].reshape(3, 1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.51 µs per loop

In [143]: %timeit np.diag(d.take(index, axis=1)).reshape(3, 1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.81 µs per loop

In [146]: %timeit d.ravel()[np.arange(d.shape[0])*d.shape[1]+index].reshape(3, 1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.56 µs per loop
```

This method is about twice as fast as both proposed alternatives.

**EDIT 2: An even better method**

Based on @Emanuele Paulinis' version but reduced number of operations outperforms all on large arrays 10k rows by 100 columns.

```
In [199]: %timeit d[(np.arange(index.size), index)].reshape(index.size, 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 364 µs per loop

In [200]: %timeit d.ravel()[np.arange(d.shape[0])*d.shape[1]+index].reshape(index.size, 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.22 ms per loop
```

So if speed is of essence:

```
d[(np.arange(index.size), index)].reshape(index.size, 1)
```

Comment: I said "more efficient" because your solution passes through a N*N matrix of which you discard all but the diagonal. So I assume (but I have not checked) that your solution is quadratic in the length of index while mine should be linear.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini True that given a large enough size yours should be more efficient.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini for 10k rows and 100 columns yours is about 150 times faster so I suppose it's a matter of problem size

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini made tweak to yours that I think is more clear and is more than 10-fold faster.